# Highlighting values above a threshold using lattice in R xyplot

Tags: r, lattice, threshold

Hi I am trying to highlight values above 35 degrees celsius as red points and add the months as well as year to the x axis. I admittedly modified [this script](http://www.sr.bham.ac.uk/~ajrs/R/gallery/). I am new to R and would really appreciate the help. Also, another package will do.

here is a sample of the data and code.

```
Date    reference   shade   sun
2010-03-01  NA  50.6221 53.3561
2010-03-02  NA  38.1599 40.3847
2010-03-03  NA  34.8627 38.3919
2010-03-04  NA  33.4927 35.0268
2011-04-22  NA  38.2654 45.972
2011-04-23  NA  38.0786 37.2561
2013-07-18  13.7    13.7    13.7
2013-07-19  18.7    19.1    18.7
2014-05-26  20.6    20.7    23.7
2014-05-27  21.6    22.2    24.6
2014-05-28  17.1    17.7    22.1

require(lattice)


require(RColorBrewer)
colset <- brewer.pal(3, "Set1")

trellis.device(device="pdf", file="nestbox_temp_profiles.pdf", height=11, 
             width=7.5, color=TRUE)

lab.reference <- "Reference Area"
lab.shade <- "Shaded Nest-boxes"
lab.sun <- "Sun Exposed Nest-boxes"

my.strip <- function(which.given, which.panel, ...) {
  strip.labels <- c(lab.shade, lab.sun, lab.reference)
  panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1, col="#ffe5cc", border=1)
  panel.text(x=0.5, y=0.5, adj=c(0.5, 0.55), cex=0.95,
             lab=strip.labels[which.panel[which.given]])
} #--Custom strip function:

Nestemp$Date <- strptime(Nestemp$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")#--Define X axis date range:

xlim <- range(Nestemp$Date)

d <- seq(from=as.Date("2010-03-01"), to=as.Date("2015-03-01"), by=365/4) #--Define annual quarters for plot grid line markers:


col.raw <- "#377EB8"    
col.lm <- "red"


plot1<-xyplot(sun + shade + reference ~ Date, data=Nestemp, 
       scales=list(y="free", rot=0), 
       strip=my.strip, outer=TRUE, layout=c(1, 3, 1), ylab="Temperature (celsius)", xlab="",
       panel=function(x, y, groups=groups) {panel.grid(h=0, v=0) panel.abline(v=d, col="grey90") panel.xyplot(x, y, ..., type="p", col=col.raw, lwd=0.8) panel.abline(h=35, lty=2, col="red", lwd=1)},

key=list(text=list(c("Nestbox Temperature", "Threshold 35 degrees celsius")),
                title="Daily Maximum Nest box Temperature",
                col=c(col.raw, col.lm), lty=c(1, 2),
                columns=2, cex=0.95,
                lines=TRUE),)

plot1
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of plot is easy to make using `ggplot2` (this example uses the example dataset `mtcars`):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = mpg > 30)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue'), breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers Paul, I have tried that but lose the relative time series and with multiple years as well as another factor of box type (i.e. shade sun or reference) becomes messy. I can post this as an example in a few hours.

Comment: By the sounds of what you are trying to do, `ggplot2` should be able to handle that nicely. Post an example and maybe we can help you polish it up.

Comment: It worked, thanks Paul. I used ggplot2 and foramtted date column with df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y/%m/%d")

Answer (score 1):

I used  a date time stamp to format my date column. I then used @PaulHiemstra 's suggestion with ggplot2.

sample df

```
Date    sseye   max month   season
2009/10/6   Shaded Nest-boxes   29.9508 11  Non-breeding season
2011/06/7   Sun Exposed Nest-boxes  38.1586 11  Non-breeding season
2013/11/10  Shaded Nest-boxes   29.2015 11  Non-breeding season
2014/05/9   Sun Exposed Nest-boxes  39.4666 11  Non-breeding season

library(scales) # for units
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plyr)
library(ffbase)


Nestemp2$Date <- as.Date(Nestemp2$Date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
plotnest=ggplot(Nestemp2, aes(x=Date, y=max, color = max > 35)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'red')) +
```

Next I wanted to add vertical and horizontal lines at particalr dates and a value

```
geom_hline(yintercept=35, colour="red", linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="black")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2010-04-01")), vjust=0.5, linetype=2) + 
  annotate("text", x=as.Date("2010-04-10"), y=25, label=" Not Breeding", angle=90, size=3,  vjust=-1, hjust=1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2010-10-01"), vjust=0.5), linetype=2) + 
  annotate("text", x=as.Date("2010-09-30"), y=25, label=" Breeding", angle=90, size=3,  vjust=-1, hjust=1) +
```

My df column consists of multiple factors for nest location (sun, shade and a reference location) so I used facet wrap to make a panel plot consisting of the factor  ~ssey (three levels (sun, shade and reference). I cannot post a picture but it looks sweet.

```
ylab("Temperature (c)") +
  facet_wrap( ~ sseye, ncol=1) +                  #this is what puts them in a grid
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,60)) +    

  theme_bw() + theme(
  strip.text.x = element_text(size=16),           #sets the size of the title to each grid section as 10
  strip.background = element_blank(),             #removes the grey background in the title of each grid section
  axis.text.x = theme_text(size=16),               #sets the x axis tick text size to 8
  axis.text.y = theme_text(size=16),               #sets the y axis tick text size to 8
  axis.title.x=theme_blank(),                     #removes the x axis title
  axis.title.y=theme_text(size=16, vjust = .3),               #sets the y axis title to size 10
  axis.line=theme_segment(colour="black"),        #sets the axis lines
  panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),               #removes minor grid lines
  panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),               #removes major grid lines
  panel.border=theme_blank(),                     #removes the border around the graph
  panel.background=theme_blank(),                 #removes the grey background of the plot
  legend.justification=c(10,10), 
  legend.position=c(10,10), # Position legend in top right
  legend.title=element_blank(),
  legend.text = theme_blank(),
  legend.title = theme_blank(),                   #removes the legend title
  legend.key = theme_blank())   

plotnest
```

[image: ggplot2 time series with factors and facetwrap]

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, could you add an image with the result?

Comment: Yeh sure. In the image I repeated the geom_vline() code at all the dates I wanted. Essentially a copy paste and only changing the years within the code. I didn't provide this but the first vertical line code is there.